# How to configure JSON deserialization in Spring to set null values if JSON property is empty string?

Tags: java, json, spring, json-deserialization

I created custom JsonDeserializer for that can be applied to any field with type String.

```
public class EmptyToNullStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = jp.getText();
        return "" == text ? null : text;
    }
}
```

It can be used in models.

```
class SomeClass {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNullStringDeserializer.class)
    private String someField;
}
```

It converts JSON

```
{"someField": ""}
```

into Java object where `someField` equals to `null` (not `""`)

**Question:** How to create generic `JsonDeserializer` that sets `null` to all Java object fields that equals to `""` in JSON?
It should be used as:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNullStringDeserializer.class)
class SomeClass {
        private String someField;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This more of a Jackson question than a Spring question.  You would just need to register your custom deserializer with the **ObjectMapper**...

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
module.addDeserializer(String.class, new EmptyToNullStringDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

How you get access to that ObjectMapper depends on if you are using Spring Boot or just plain Spring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your custom deserializer with ObjectMapper